# Javascript to change asp:textbox visible property to true

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to create an form in which a textbox should be shown or hidden  based on the dropdown & also validate the textbox if it is shown only.

Can anyone help me in this?

```
<asp:DropDownList 
    ID="txt_days" 
    CssClass="txt_drpbx" 
    runat="server"  
    siz="10" 
>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
    ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" 
    runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="txt_days" 
    ForeColor="Red" 
    ErrorMessage="Please Select No of days on leave" 
    InitialValue="0" 
    ValidationGroup="fdbk_chk"
>*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:TextBox 
    ID="txt_todate" 
    runat="server" 
    ReadOnly="true" 
    Visible="false" 
    CssClass="txt_bx"
></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
    ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
    runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="txt_todate" 
    ForeColor="Red" 
    ErrorMessage="Please Select Feedback Given For" 
    ValidationGroup="fdbk_chk"
>*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:Button 
    ID="btn_submit" 
    Text="Submit" 
    CssClass="btn_button" 
    runat="server" 
    onclick="btn_submit_Click" 
    ValidationGroup="fdbk_chk" 
/>
<asp:ValidationSummary 
    ID="ValidationSummary1" 
    runat="server" 
    HeaderText="Some fields are missing" 
    ShowMessageBox="True" 
    ShowSummary="False" 
    ValidationGroup="fdbk_chk" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>

    function ShowHideTextBox(ddlId)
    {
         var ddl = document.getElementById(ddlId.id);

         if(ddl.value == 1)  //your condition
         {
             document.getElementById('txt_todate').style.display = 'none';
          }
         else
         {
             document.getElementById('txt_todate').style.display = '';

         }
    }
```

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="txt_days" CssClass="txt_drpbx" runat="server"  siz="10" onchange="ShowHideTextBox(this);" 

<asp:TextBox ID="txt_todate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false" CssClass="txt_bx"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using visible, set its css to display:none

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txt_todate" runat="server" style="display:none;" CssClass="txt_bx">
  </asp:TextBox>
```

and add your dropdownlist  onchange

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDays" CssClass="txt_drpbx" runat="server" onchange="ShowHide();">
   <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="Show" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="Hide" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

in script;

```
 <script  type="text/javascript">
   function ShowHide(){
    var value = document.getElementById('ddlDays').value;
    var theControl = document.getElementById("txt_todate");
    if(value != 1){  // only when value is 1 it must show
       theControl.style.display = "none";
     }
    else{
       theControl.style.display = "block";
    }
   }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried display none at my end it was not working, but I was successful with visibility property. So, try this:

```
function Validate()
{
     var dropdown = document.getElementById('ID of the dropdown');

     if(Condition which you want) 
     {
         document.getElementById('txt_todate').style.visibility= true;
      }
     else
     {
         document.getElementById('txt_todate').style.visibility= false;

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Control id on server side is not the same in client side.
To be the same and to can use ID with javascript you must add to your server controls ClientIDMode="Static"

As example:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDays" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="txt_drpbx" runat="server" onchange="ShowHide();">
```